# org.dozer.MappingProcessor - Field mapping error ByteArray

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, dozer

I have following entity, DTO class and dozer mapping file. I'm trying to copy the hibernate entity which contains a 2 dim byte array to the new DTO using dozer mapping. Getting the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch.

Any idea?

mapping file:

```
<mapping map-id="i" wildcard="false">
        <class-a>com.csinfra.jdbmon.web.client.dto.Config.HostGroups.HostGroup.CheckGroup.Check.Type.MultiResult</class-a>
        <class-b>com.csinfra.jdbmon.web.client.dto.MultiResultDTO</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>id</a>
            <b>id</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>columns</a>
            <b>columns</b>
        </field>                        
    </mapping>
```

Entity class:

```
    @Entity(name="multiResult")
@Table(name="multiResult")
public static class MultiResult implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "columns",length = 10000)
    private byte[][] columns;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public byte[][] getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(byte[][] columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
}
```

DTO class:

```
public class MultiResultDTO implements IsSerializable {

    private Long id;
    private byte[][] columns;

    public MultiResultDTO(){}

    public byte[][] getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(byte[][] columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

Exception:

```
19165 ERROR org.dozer.MappingProcessor - Field mapping error -->
  MapId: null
  Type: null
  Source parent class: com.csinfra.jdbmon.web.client.dto.Config$HostGroups$HostGroup$CheckGroup$Check$Type$MultiResult
  Source field name: columns
  Source field type: class [[B
  Source field value: [[B@127a7396
  Dest parent class: com.csinfra.jdbmon.web.client.dto.MultiResultDTO
  Dest field name: columns
  Dest field type: [[B
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.addToPrimitiveArray(MappingProcessor.java:712)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapArrayToArray(MappingProcessor.java:629)
    . . .
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either a design decision or a bug. I reproduced it [in a simpler setting](https://github.com/starikoff/Dozer2DArrayBug.git) and [filed](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/544). It seems that it's possible to patch the code to at least support multidimensional arrays (multidimensional collections still don't work this way), but I only [did that](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/544#issuecomment-357401132) as a proof of concept for the "happy path" of constructing a totally new object, omitting the part where the destination object might already have non-null fields. The amount of work needed to be done to support that in all cases is quite big which hints that it is a design decision to only support 1-d collections and arrays. But that's just my take and I see that code for the first time, maybe we will get more info from experienced Dozer developers at some point.

---

With that said, you can easily overcome that in your particular case by writing a custom converter for your "columns" parameter (or actually for any 1-d or 2-d byte array).

A longer but somewhat cleaner way IMO (doesn't rely on Dozer taking any part in that, as that seems somewhat *unreliable*): define a converter class

```
public class ByteArray2dConverter extends DozerConverter<byte[][], byte[][]> {

    public ByteArray2dConverter() {
        super(byte[][].class, byte[][].class);
    }

    public byte[][] convertTo(byte[][] source, byte[][] destination) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[][] result = new byte[source.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            byte[] element = source[i];
            if (element != null) {
                result[i] = Arrays.copyOf(element, element.length);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public byte[][] convertFrom(byte[][] source, byte[][] destination) {
        return convertTo(source, destination);
    }
}
```

...and add a `custom-converter` attribute to the "columns" field in your XML mapping file:

```
<mapping map-id="i" wildcard="false">
    <class-a>com.csinfra.jdbmon.web.client.dto.Config.HostGroups.HostGroup.CheckGroup.Check.Type.MultiResult</class-a>
    <class-b>com.csinfra.jdbmon.web.client.dto.MultiResultDTO</class-b>
    ...
    <field custom-converter="com.csinfra...ByteArray2dConverter">
        <a>columns</a>
        <b>columns</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

---

Alternatively, you can save some typing if you allow Dozer to map the "top-level" array and only use a custom converter for the second level: define a converter

```
public class ByteArray1dConverter extends DozerConverter<byte[], byte[]> {

    public ByteArray1dConverter() {
        super(byte[].class, byte[].class);
    }

    public byte[] convertTo(byte[] source, byte[] destination) {
        return source == null ? null : Arrays.copyOf(source, source.length);
    }

    public byte[] convertFrom(byte[] source, byte[] destination) {
        return convertTo(source, destination);
    }
}
```

...and then in the mappings XML add a section (on the same level as the "mapping" section):

```
...
<configuration>
    <custom-converters>
        <converter
                type="com.csinfra...ByteArray1dConverter">
            <class-a>[B</class-a>
            <class-b>[B</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>
</configuration>
<mapping map-id="i" wildcard="false">
    ...
```

This way you tell Dozer to use your converter in all conversions between two byte arrays (you can do the same in the previous case instead of defining a custom-converter on the field level in the mapping XML).

---

Yet another option is to use a 1-d array of objects each having a 1-d byte array, Dozer is fine with that. Something like `Column[] columns`, where the Column class has a field `byte[] columnBytes`.

Comment: Offtopic: with that said, I am highly skeptical about solutions like this (dozer) that bring magic and complexity into projects, at the same time reducing type-safety, refactoring safety etc. And it's slower and less efficient than the straightforward "copying" code, too.